# CSV processing: moving column/row value to different row where column value matches

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file with around 50 columns, can be anywhere between 20 and 100 rows.

The individual records have IDs, and some records can be in a group of 2. Essentially what I need to do is add an ID to the same row that another ID in that group is in. Example:

```
ID     ,group,blank column
2019-1 ,     ,
2019-2 ,GRP1 ,
2019-3 ,GRP2 ,
2019-4 ,GRP1 ,
2019-5 ,     ,
2019-6 ,GRP2 ,
```

And the output I would like is:

```
ID     ,group,blank column
2019-1 ,     ,
2019-2 ,GRP1 ,2019-4
2019-3 ,GRP2 ,2019-6
2019-5 ,     ,
```

In my attempts using awk, I haven't had any luck. I either end up leaving out rows that have no group, or I end up repeating values.

Comment: and what with a third line with GRP1 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -a -F, -ne 'if($F[1]=~/\S/) { push @{$d{$F[1]}}, $F[0]; } else { print ; }
  END {
    for(keys %d){
      print shift @{$d{$_}},",$_, ",@{$d{$_}},"\n"
    }
  }' my.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This absolutely does what is intended. I have next to no experience with perl however, and I am trying to implement this for use with a file that has 50+ columns. I'm not sure of the best way to accomplish this however. I basically need it to go in, and update the columns I've mentioned, but still print all the other information.